# Jquery clone issue in Foreach function

Tags: php, jquery

I need to clone a selected item , in a language list, and copy it inside a div. The problem is that the clone function , copy 3 times the same div.

```
<div class="language-selected"></div>
    <ul id="select-language">
    <?php foreach ($this->getLanguage() as $_code => $_name): ?>
        <li class="<?php if($_code==$this->getCurrentLangCode()): ?><?php echo $_code ?> selected<?php endif; ?>">
            <a href="#">
                <?php echo $_code ?>
             </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

$j( '#select-language li.selected a').clone().appendTo(".language-selected");
```

The resulti is :

```
<div class="language-selected">
<a href="#">ENG</a>
<a href="#">ENG</a>
<a href="#">ENG</a>
</div>
```

Comment: check if there are 3 <li> being generated in original HTML

Comment: its all ok, if i comment the function, i don't see anything

Answer (score 0):

```
Probably you need to change the selector of the jquery element.

with `#select-language li.selected a` you select only the active element.

You can try with `#select-language li a` that will select all `a` elements.
```

---

EDIT:
Sorry i missundertend the question.

it should work as you have done:
i have wrote a fiddle an works as you intend:
[fiddle](http://codepen.io/eparisio/pen/MeWLJO?editors=1010)

EDIT 2:

i see your answer, the problem is that the condition in php will not take in consideration the `selected` class and is added to all the `li` elements, you should add to the language check the addition of the `selected` class.

Comment: not work, with this change jquery move all elements, not only the selected

Answer (score 0):

Fixed :

```
$j( '#select-language li.selected a').first().clone().appendTo(".language-selected");
```